# New navigation not showing up

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-nav

I've checked the check-box at the bottom of my user preferences page.

---

[image]

---

But the navigation on the website stays exactly the same. Here it is before.

---

[image]

---

And here it is after I checked the box.

---

[image]

Comment: I think they're releasing the new nav to users in batches. I had it selected on my profile for a while before I started seeing it. They're still testing it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the text directly under the checkbox in your screenshot:

> You are currently waiting to be part of the new navigation test group.

So, it shouldn't be showing for you yet, as you're not part of the test group yet.